# File search in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filesystems

How can I create a program, that automaticly searches for specific files on Windows.
For example, the directory is `F:\search` and the given file `betyoucant.mp4` is in `F:\search\Highlights\APEX`
The problem is that there are a lot of folders in disk F. Question may seem wierd, but I just do not want to do a lot of loops.

If there are any more efficient way than recursive thing?
recursive thing

```
fun File.searchFile(targetFile: String) {
if (this.isDirectory) {
    val files = this.listFiles()
    if (files != null) {
        for (file in files) {
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                file.searchFile(targetFile)
            } else {
                if (file.name == targetFile) {
                    println("Found file: ${file.absolutePath}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}